# Wpf set owner window not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main Window that I want it to be the owner of all other windows

from the class of the main window this was the code

```
private voide btn_Click()
 {
      SomeWindow w = new SomeWindow()
      w.Owner = this;
      w.Show();
  }
```

also tried

```
w.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
```

but  it never works

Comment: Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: I really have no clue .. it is supposed to be that simple

Comment: I meant what are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to make some window a child of the main window

Comment: when debugging it gets the main window correctly and sets it to be the owner of the child window .. but when the app visualizes the two windows are separated

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, it seems that you want something like this:

```
 w.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

or you might want to do:

```
w.ShowDialog();
```

Note what [Owner-Child relationships do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Once this relationship is established, the following behaviors are exhibited:
>
> - If an owner window is minimized, all its owned windows are minimized as well.
> - If an owned window is minimized, its owner is not minimized.
> - If an owner window is maximized, both the owner window and its owned windows are restored.
> - An owner window can never cover an owned window.
> - Owned windows that were not opened using ShowDialog are not modal. The user can still interact with the owner window.
> - If you close an owner window, its owned windows are also closed.
> - If an owned window was opened by its owner window using Show, and the owner window is closed, the owned window's Closing event is not raised.

Comment: that helped too .. but for more details .. in Windows Forms when you set the parent of a child window the child never goes outside of the parents frame .. I want the behaviour to be like that